# MySQL Unable to select a specific field value?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

While generating some external reports for Kayako Fusion using MySQL Queries, I have encountered a strange and annoying problem. One of the fields in a table contains a 'TEXT' field which can contain one of two values: 41 or 40. If the end user doesn't select one of the values, the default is NULL. (I am unable to change that).

So, when attempting to do a simple:

```
WHERE swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue = '41'
```

It then also returns records with a NULL (or maybe '') value.

The same applies to:

```
WHERE swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue = '40'
```

We also get the NULL records (Which is kind of accurate because we treat NULL as 40.

For simple reference the value of 40 is for non-chargeable work and the value of 41 is for chargeable work.

What am I missing, or is there a workaround?

[image: Screen Shot]

Here is the nasty original SQL statement:

```
SELECT
swtickets.ticketid AS `Ticket ID`,
swtickettimetracks.tickettimetrackid AS `Track ID`,
swtickets.ticketmaskid AS `TicketMASK`,
(
    SELECT
        swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue
    FROM
        swcustomfieldvalues,
        swcustomfields
    WHERE
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid = swcustomfields.customfieldid
    AND swtickets.ticketid = swcustomfieldvalues.typeid
    AND swcustomfields.title = 'Member Company'
    ORDER BY
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldvalueid DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS MemberCompany,
(
    SELECT
        swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue
    FROM
        swcustomfieldvalues,
        swcustomfields
    WHERE
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid = swcustomfields.customfieldid
    AND swtickets.ticketid = swcustomfieldvalues.typeid
    AND swcustomfields.title = 'Member Name'
    ORDER BY
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldvalueid DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS MemberName,
(
    SELECT
        swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue
    FROM
        swcustomfieldvalues,
        swcustomfields
    WHERE
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid = swcustomfields.customfieldid
    AND swtickets.ticketid = swcustomfieldvalues.typeid
    AND swcustomfields.title = 'Chargeable'
    AND swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue = '41'
    ORDER BY
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldvalueid ASC
    LIMIT 1
) AS `Chg`,
swtickets.`subject` AS `Subject`,
swtickets.departmenttitle AS Category,
FROM_UNIXTIME(
    swtickettimetracks.workdateline,
    '%Y-%m-%d'
) AS `workDateline`,
FROM_UNIXTIME(
    swtickettimetracks.dateline,
    '%Y-%m-%d'
) AS `dateline`,
swtickettimetracks.timespent AS `Time Spent`,
swtickets.timeworked / 60 AS `Time Worked`
FROM
    swtickets
RIGHT OUTER JOIN swusers ON swtickets.userid = swusers.userid
INNER JOIN swuserorganizations ON swuserorganizations.userorganizationid = swusers.userorganizationid
INNER JOIN swtickettimetracks ON swtickettimetracks.ticketid = swtickets.ticketid
WHERE
    swuserorganizations.organizationname = 'Clarence Professional Offices'
AND (
    swtickets.ticketstatustitle = 'Closed'
    OR swtickets.ticketstatustitle = 'Completed'
)
AND swtickets.ticketid = '2895'
GROUP BY
    `Ticket ID`,
    `Track ID`
```

Please be kind to me, I'm a novice ;)

Breaking out the individual Sub Selects (which are unavoidable) I can prove that this individual one for obtaining the Custom Field 'Chargeable' with a Value of '41' against a specific Ticket '2895' actually Works! See:

```
SELECT
        swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue,
        swtickets.ticketid

    FROM
        swcustomfieldvalues,
        swcustomfields,
        swtickets
    WHERE
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldid = swcustomfields.customfieldid
    AND swtickets.ticketid = swcustomfieldvalues.typeid
    AND swcustomfields.title = 'Chargeable'
    AND swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue = '40'
    AND swtickets.ticketid = '2895'
    ORDER BY
        swcustomfieldvalues.customfieldvalueid ASC
```

It Returns a TRUE, as I know that this Ticket is NON Chargeable (40). If I change the Value to '41' (Chargeable) it returns False (No Records).

The Whole SQL Statement (Original) should return: ALL Tickets that are Chargeable within a Date Range, showing me

Ticket ID/Ticket Mask, Track ID, Member Company, Member Name, Chargeable? (40|41), Subject, Category, WorkDateline, Dateline, Time Spent, and Time Worked.

Then in PHP I do some more manipulation to do a 'Break On' for Sub Totals etc. But I digress.

Comment: The screen shot shows part but not all of the query.  If you run just the part that refers to swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue being 41, does it still return records with null in that field?

Comment: Hi Dan, much more added to the description above including full SQL thank you.

Comment: Any specific reason of using `RIGHT OUTER JOIN swusers`? if not try with `inner join` 99% this will be the cause of getting null records.

Comment: what do you mean it returns TRUE or FALSE? what is the value of `swcustomfieldvalues.fieldvalue` in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot the problem shows up clearly: you are returning the result of your select directly into the main SELECT statement, using a nested query.

This nested query does not return nulls when you filter  fieldvalue = '40', it just doesn't return *anything* (i.e.: no row is returned), which leads to showing NULL in the main SELECT statement.

If you want to actually filter out the records not matching the criteria you mention (fieldvalue) then you should include this nested subquery in the JOIN section to actually reduce the resulting recordsets.

I can't give you the query since you didn't paste it here, but if you need I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you so much Sebas! I have added the nasty SQL for your review. Anything you can do to help is much appreciated.

Comment: amongst all of your nested subqueries (the one used in the select part) which one are real filters and which one should return null if no record are returned?

Comment: hmm i'm not so sure of what is your expected result actually, i would need some details

Comment: Please see additional info added to my issue as above. Thank you (again) !